# How I can remove / add types in postresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm trying to make small accounting app. I already have bills prices like: maintenance, heating, garbage collection, sewerage and electricity. But I started thinking what if I would like to add / remove field. Like grass cutting expense or accidental expense or anything else? I realised that my db is not flexible enough. App will need to store previous receipts as well, so if I have some fields that are no longer included, they will need to be not included in new receipts, but be there in old receipts. Vice versa, if I decided to add extra expense for this month, it should be in this month only.

How can I make it so that I can add / remove fields?
[image]

Comment: Those shouldn't be columns. You should have a one-to-many relation from bill to e.g. `bill_item` and each item has a date, value, due_date and a type

Comment: How can I switch them on / off though? Like I want certain bill item to be available for first, fifth, eighth month? And is it possible to make them included not in all flats?

Comment: You can have one based table that have all the possible fields. then one month receipt all the fields that is not null to cast  to  json. or your question is like how to dynamic select columns based on columns values is null or  not. for example column A in june-2022 is null then June2022 receipt should not contain columnA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly made a basic model for you so you better unterstand how to normalize such a use case properly:

[image: Bill model]

Now to a concrete example:
Let's say you want to create a new bill for june which has id 10. You can now create as many bill items as you need. Let's say you want water, maintenance and heating. You just need to add all types of service to the bill_type table in advance and set a price of one unit. Now you can link your individual bill_items to a specific service type and set an amount. You get the bill total as following: Join all bill_items -> Join all bill types to every bill_item -> Multiply bill_item.amount * bill_type.price -> Sum it up and done!

Hope that helps!